# "file format different from extension" when creating an xls file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an xlsx file, with this simple script:

```
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
    format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
return {
    tableToExcel:function(worksheetName){
        var table='ffgs',
            ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:'<tr><td>TEST</td></tr><tr><td>This is just a test</td></tr>'},
            href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
        return href;
    }
};
});
```

Calling it like that:

```
$scope.genReport = function() {
    var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel('sheetname');
    $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100);    
}
```

It works, anyway when opening it on excel 2010 it tells me that the file format is different from the extension. Confirming the prompt opens it anyways, but I don't want for excel to show me that prompt.

I think problem is in my template variable...any ideas?

Comment: you would need to output actual xls files, which can be binary or openoffice; your code just makes an html table file which while it works, will always cause that warning.

Comment: :( and isn't there an already made js library doing the job for me?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+excel